# 'Open in browser' crashes the app

Tags: bug, android-app

when I go to click 'Open in browser' on a question, it crashes in the glorious fashion of old. I wouldn't mind- but it doesn't open the question in chrome. Got any insight on this, guys?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, been clicking "send report" after each crash for months.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my end.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara it seems to apply if you have not opened chrome since last boot.

Comment: It happens no matter if or when I've opened Chrome.

Comment: @davidism results may vary? What phone are you using?

Comment: Nexus 6p. Happenes on marshmallow and nougat.

Comment: @davidism Bush SPIRA b3 here, Marshmallow. Seems to correlate

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, app v1.0.89. Based on a quick experiment, this happens when SE app is set to always open supported links (i.e. SE links). Setting it to "Ask every time" fixes the issue for now. (The setting is accessible from *App info - Open by default*)

Comment: @qwer In fact, same results here when done your way.

Comment: To come back to this, logs show that It Kinda loops and crashes - you open in browser, which then returns it back to the SE app, Which screams "WHAT THE HELL!" and crashes. GG.

Comment: @Luke Getting the broom out? Fair enough, they seem close to each other. Not sure if they are one and they same, but Andrews wording may be to blame. Can we merge, since we've got some stuff here?

Comment: @Dan that and a not so subtle bump 

Comment: @Luke Huh. I wonder what bumped it.

Comment: @Dan, I did as the bug is still an issue

Comment: @Luke Ah. I'm blind again, as always :)